# Docker macvlan with second interface

Tags: docker, gateway, interface

I currently have two NICs ens192 10.0.0.0/24 and ens224 10.10.0.0/24. Currently docker is using ens192. I have a few containers that I would like to use ens224 so their traffic would be routed through a different gateway.

I have attempted using macvlan using the 10.10.0.0/24 subnet with the parent interface set as ens224. I then attach it to the container but am unable access anything on that subnet.

I have also attempted this with ens192 and get the same results.

Maybe this is not possible or I am going about it the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

OS is OpenMediaVault on Vmware ESXI.

This is the command I use to create the macvlan network.

```
docker network create -d macvlan -o parent=ens224 --subnet 10.10.0.0/24 --gateway 10.10.0.1 --ip-range 10.10.0.200/27 mymacvlan
```

Comment: Please include MACVLAN configuration file.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm on the same boat.